# android: custom dial screen

Tags: android

i want to develop a screen that is similar to default dial screen.
and want to override the functionality for the call button.
Can you suggest the best method to implement this?

Can I use the andorid's dial screen and override the call button functionality or need to develop the entire view too?

If we need to develope the screen from the scratch, what layout is best suited for this..(gridview/tablelayout)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can open phone's dial screen through any of following

Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_DIAL); startActivity (intent);

Also, you should register the custom dialscreen as follows in the manifest:

```
<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<activity
    android:name=".MyDialerApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <intent-filter android:priority="100" >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />

    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```