# How to make a custom dial icon for the numbers on an android touch screen (image below for context)?

Tags: python, android

I want to make a custom key dial icon for android first then later an app compatible with all other phone OS. I don't know how to do it using anything beside python like XML and Java. The following picture is a model of the dial pad I want to make vs what it originally looks like. It only needs images.

Would you kindly inform me where I went wrong in the code, what to add, easier alternatives (programming languages,code) and inform me in a simple step by step numbered basis. Thank you

Tried code Python:

```
# Import necessary Kivy modules
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from jnius import autoclass

# Access the Android Environment class
Environment = autoclass('android.os.Environment')
File = autoclass('java.io.File')

class CustomDialPad(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = GridLayout(cols=3)  # Create a grid layout with 3 columns

        # Get the path to the external storage directory on Android
        external_storage_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()

        # Define the filenames of images in the storage directory to use for buttons
        image_files = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg', 'image5.jpg', 'image6.jpg', 'image7.jpg', 'image8.jpg', 'image9.jpg', 'image0.jpg']

        # Create buttons with images from storage instead of numbers
        for image_file in image_files:
            image_path = File(external_storage_path, image_file).getAbsolutePath()
            button = Button(background_normal=image_path, background_down=image_path)
            layout.add_widget(button)

        return layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CustomDialPad().run()
```

In this code:

```
We import the necessary Kivy modules and the autoclass function from Pyjnius to access Android classes.
We use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() to get the path to the external storage directory on Android.
We define a list of image filenames in the storage directory to be used for each button.
We create buttons for each image file, setting the background_normal and background_down properties to display the images.
Finally, we run the CustomDialPad application.
```

[image]

Looked at:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063094/android-custom-dial-screen)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-can-you-make-a-custom-keyboard-in-android)